# Python code working in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I have recently coded an Algorithm completely on Python, The Code is working absolutely fine in Windows, but When I am trying to execute it in Linux(Debian), I am getting this error,

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file BlackBox.py on line 154, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

This is the code in line 154,

```
Encoded_Password = e_password.encode('utf-8') + self._salt[:16]
```

I want to know why it is not working on my Linux environemnt.
Please help me out.

Comment: Put `# -*- coding -*- : utf-8` at the first line of the source. Follow the link in the error message.

Comment: @falsetru That does not always work, not on all systems atleast.

Comment: @falsetru I've tried `# encoding=utf-8` on my windows 8 system, and for some apparent reason, it does not work, but `encoding=utf-8` works fine. Is there any documentation regarding this that you've come across?

Comment: @falsetru I'm using windows 8 64 bit. And I fail to understand your second question.

Comment: Is the file encoded with utf-8 encoding? The first question was which version of **python** ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not adding the encoding comment at the top:

```
# encoding=utf-8
```